# R Gist script gives error in RGui console but works fine in RStudio console - Windows 8 R3.1.2(64 bit)

Tags: r

The below works fine in RStudio console :

```
source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ajit555/f7a3d2ccfd5ab305cd3f/raw/a931585306ccb977ae13b8e2b20e78a4a71fdd2c/HelloGist.R")
```

But when run in RGui console, gives the below error:

```
    source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ajit555/f7a3d2ccfd5ab305cd3f/raw/a931585306ccb977ae13b8e2b20e78a4a71fdd2c/HelloGist.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : unsupported URL scheme
```

what do I need to do to run properly in RGui console?

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the solution. Silly of me not to search it before posting.

Comment: In RGui shortcut in Windows, added --internet2 as - "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64\Rgui.exe" --internet2